# Checking if a datatable column has value or not in C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

This is my datatable

```
DataTable get_order_info = objDUT.GetDataTable("select * from investment_orders where order_id =" + dr["order_id"]);
```

In this datatable there is a column `added_date`.

I want to apply my method if the column `added_date != null`

I have written this code :

```
if (get_order_info.Columns.Contains("added_time") != null)
{
    var secondsSince1970 = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse("01.01.1970 00:00:00");
    difference = Convert.ToInt64(secondsSince1970.TotalSeconds) - Convert.ToInt64(get_order_info.Rows[0]["added_time"]);
}
else
{
    Label1.Text = "fail";
}
```

but it is showing an error

> Input string was not in a correct format

Please help me.

Comment: `So, I want to apply my method if the column "added_date"  !=null` but you're checking "added_time".

Comment: You're checking whether a column called `added_time` exists in the datatable, rather than checking that the value contained in the `added_time` column in your datarow contains a value. Quite a big difference there.

Comment: don't `Convert.ToInt64` use `int.TryParse`. Also, `string.IsNullOrEmpty` might be useful

Answer (score 2):

Answering only to fix the error message You mentioned, it seems You used wrong `DateTime` format.
Try to change:

```
DateTime.Parse("01.01.1970 00:00:00");
```

into:

```
DateTime.Parse("1970-01-01 00:00:00", System.CultureInfo.Globalization.InvariantCulture);
```

As an alternative, You can explicitly specify format You want to use:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("01.01.1970 00:00:00", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.CultureInfo.Globalization.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you are wanting to do is to actually determine if the field has a value, you would need to do the following:

```
foreach(DataRow row in myTable.Rows)
{
    if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("added_time") && !DBNull.Value.Equals(row["added_time"])) 
    { 
         DateTime theValue = (DateTime)row["added_time"];

    }
}
```

Comment: string added_date = get_order_info.Rows[0]["added_time"].ToString();
            if (added_date ==null)
            {
                investment_earning_time_first_difference = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                var secondsSince1970 = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse("01.01.1970 00:00:00");
                investment_earning_time_first_difference = Convert.ToInt64(secondsSince1970.TotalSeconds) - Convert.ToInt64(get_order_info.Rows[0]["added_time"]);                             
            }   i wrote the above code which shows no error. but a problem

Comment: problem is if(added_date) == null , the system is entering the function for if(added_date) != null